# How to call a servlet from a jQuery's $.ajax() function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to call a servlet from jQuery's .ajax() function.Ajax call does not go to servlet,when i call this function s.o.p statement is not printed in console, Any ideas?For Any help thanks in advance.

```
This is my code:
<!--Html code:-->
<form id="ajaxform" action="weeklyMarks" method="post">
    <table>
        <td>
            <label id="stForm" for="Marks">Marks Obtained:</label>
            <input type="text" id="stMarks" name="stMarks" style="margin-left: 33px; width: 150px;" />     
            <label id="stMarksError" style="display: none; color: red;">*Please enter marks</label>
            <br>
            <br>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Add" id="addButton" class="btn-warning" style="margin-left: 200px;"" onclick="addSubjectMarks() ">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
//ajax call from jsp page
function addSubjectMarks(){  
 var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
 var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
 var selectedStudent=document.getElementById("selectedStudent").value;
 var selectedSubject=document.getElementById("selectedSubject").value;
 var marks=document.getElementById("stMarks").value;
  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: formURL,  
    data:postData,
    success: function(data,status){  

      alert(status);

    }                
  });  
}
```

```
//servlet is:this servlet having url weeklyMaks
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("stMarks"));
}

my web.xml code is:

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>week</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.studentmodels.WeeklyMarks</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>week</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/weeklyMarks</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<display-name>Students</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>Home.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.exception</exception-type>
    <location>/login.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: are you sure `this` is what you think it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be two causes of this error :
1. It can cause if you have written WebServlet Path in the .java file as well as in the web.xml . Removing it from any one location will work for you.

Like below:

In the .java file

```
    @WebServlet("/weeklyMarks")
```

and in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>week</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.studentmodels.WeeklyMarks</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>week</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/weeklyMarks</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But from your given code I can see you have mentioned only in web.xml
Second reason of causing this issue may be as below:

2.javamail.jar is missing. Add javamail.jar to your tomcat lib folder. Or If u have any Maven projects in your workspace open then add the commons-logging JAR to your project by adding the following dependency to your pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: great :) which one out of two option worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add it in web.xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ajaxtry</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
<servlet-name>ProcessForm</servlet-name> //url given in ajax call
<servlet-class>com.ajaxtry.web.ProcesFormServlet</servlet-class>//servlet class path
  </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ProcessForm</servlet-name> //url given in ajax call
<url-pattern>/ProcessForm</url-pattern> //url given in ajax call
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: this is in  added in web.xml file,but it gives Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start error and  Destroying ProtocolHandler error

Comment: please help me in finding a solution.